# How to convert an int to char * in C?

Tags: c, char

I need to convert an int to char *. I've looker everywhere but I haven't been able to find any help.

Here's my code

```
int int_1, int_2;
char sign;
char int1, int2;
printf("Addition or Subtration of two integers (a (+ or -) b)\n");
printf("> ");

scanf("%d %s %d", &int_1, &sign, &int_2);
printf("%d %c %d\n", int_1, sign, int_2);
```

I've tried casting `int1 = (char)int_1`, but it didn't work. I've tried to input directly into char* but that doesn't work. The reason I need this is for using the execl (http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) system call. It's args are all char*'s. I have to call execl like this

```
execl("filepath", "server", &int1, &sign, &int2, NULL);
```

Help is very much appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use the user input as char*, no need to scan them as integers.
you try this.

```
char int1[8], int2[8]; //allocate more space for larger numbers

scanf("%s %s %s", int1, &sign, int2);
```

after that you can call the exec.

```
execl("filepath", "server", int1, &sign, int2, NULL);
```

Comment: I thought of that but then this is again not the best solution.

Comment: Other option in that case will be to use sprintf().

Answer (score 0):

`execl()`, as most of POSIX API, accepts null-terminated strings, not single characters. To pass a string of one character you need allocate something like `char str[2]` and then do `str[0] = (char)`whatever you want `; str[1] = '\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an `int` to `char *`, use `sprintf()` or `snprintf()`  (suggested by @Punit Soni)

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Size buffer to the maximum needs which is about 3 bits/char plus a few.
#define INT_PRINT_SIZE(type)  (sizeof (type) * CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)

int int_1;
char buf1[INT_PRINT_SIZE(int_1)];
sprintf(buf1, "%d", int_1);
```

Then call your `excel()`

```
execl("filepath", "server", buf1, ...`
```